# Why is my program not dividing correctly?

Tags: vb.net

I have a program that takes 3 numbers in a textbox and does a calculation between them, and puts the result in another textbox.
Here's the code

```
Dim def As Long
Dim work As Long
Dim mili As Long
Dim prim As Long


Private Sub calculate_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)            Handles calculate.Click
def = defense.Text
work = working.Text
mili = military.Text
prim = (def * 100000000000) + work + mili / 1000000000000
primary.Text = prim
End Sub
End Class
```

Is it because I have the variables as Long? I tried double as well and it didn't seem to work.
Basically, it's fine up to the (def*100000000000) + work + mili, but ends there and does not divide by the 1 trillion.

Comment: Make sure your multiplication is not exceeding 9.2E18

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want something like

```
prim = ((def * 100000000000) + work + mili) / 1000000000000
```

Without those parentheses, your expression is the same as

```
prim = (def * 100000000000) + work + (mili / 1000000000000)
```